# Converting KML Html Popup attributes as shapefile attributes?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, python, kml

How to convert KML Popup info into shapefile attributes while kml to shapefile conversion by using QGIS or any software.

Comment: By asking how to do the same thing in "QGIS or any software" you are effectively asking multiple questions which makes this too broad.  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to focus your question on QGIS or another particular software.  I recommend asking about the one you are most likely to use.  You can always ask about any others in separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding from the links [Best way to import KML with attributes](https://community.esri.com/thread/24664) and [Extracting attributes from KML descriptions](https://community.esri.com/thread/191262-extracting-attributes-from-kml-descriptions), There is no direct way to import KML description as Shapefile attributes. I have exported KML description to Shapefile  using open python. I have parsed kml file using pykml module and  the description content with BeautifulSoup module and generated a excel file with neccessary information (
like latitude, longitude and remaining attributes). Finally Excel file is exported as Shapefile.