# Extract values hidden in a table column using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table

I've obtained a KML and converted it to a points layer, but the values for each point appear to be hidden in the column

[image]

In the picture, the value of interest is quantity "1.1" - I'm not really sure how or why the values appear that way (the kml was exported from Matlab), and it seems like something that could be done with python code, although that's a little outside my expertise.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/converting-a-kml-to-a-layer-how-to-convert/td-p/526159 and this closed post (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285529/converting-kml-html-popup-attributes-as-shapefile-attributes) explains this is not straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML wrapped around the value you want is the same in every row, the following simple expression in Field Calculator should work.

First, create a destination field named here NewField, with data type 'double'. Then open Field Calculator and use the following expression:

```
NewField = !PopupInfo![70:-4].strip()
```

This slices out the first 70 and last 4 characters, then `.strip()` removes any leftover whitespace. What's left is coerced to a number by the output field's datatype.

Note that you may need some null handling if that 'Value:' is ever missing e.g. [Converting Text Field to Numeric in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314162/converting-text-field-to-numeric-in-arcgis-pro)